# How to solve this particular linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have this linear system:

$$
\begin{align*}
-u + v &= y_1\\
u + v &= y_2 \\
2u + v &= y_3
\end{align*} $$

After doing gaussian elimination, I get:

$$
\begin{align*}
u = y_3 - y_2 \\
v = 2y_2 - y_3 \\
y_1 -3y_2 + 2y_3 = 0 
\end{align*} $$

I'm asked to find for what values of $y_1, y_2, y_3$ this system has a solution. The answer to that would be:

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -3 & 2 \\
 \end{array} \right] * \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3 
 \end{array} \right] = 0$$

i.e. the null space. How do I find a basis for the null space though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution by far is just to guess two linearly independent vectors that satisfy the condition, such as $(3,1,0)$ and $(2,0,-1)$.

If that is not systematic enough for you, take $(1,-3,2)$ and append a known basis for the entire space, such as $\mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_2, \mathbf e_3$. Then use the Gram-Schmidt process on the resulting list of 4 vectors. You'll need to throw out one when it turns out it is not linearly independent of the precedent ones. In the resulting basis for $\mathbb R^3$, remove the first one (which will be proportional to $(1,-3,2)$); the other two are a basis for the orthogonal complement.

Comment: Thanks for the description! I didn't realize it could be done that way, but it appears guessing seems to be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly two independent vectors from the null space are $a_1 = (3, 1, 0)^t$ and $a_2 = (2, 0, -1)^t$.

Comment: And we know that you only need two because the dimension of the null space is 3-1 = 2, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in 3 dimensions, then $y_1-3y_2+2y_3=0$ is the [cartesian equation of a plane](http://www.netcomuk.co.uk/~jenolive/vect15.html). Choose values for any two of the three parameters and that will determine the third one.